# Dell Ultrabook 14z 5423 System-Installation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, dell

I have a Dell 14z 5423 and I tried to install Ubuntu, Kubuntu versions 18 and 20 without success. I upgraded the dell BIOS and still have the same error problem. The problem arises with the installation arrived on the HD Partitions. It returns: "ubi-patman failed with exit code 141". This DELL have a HD with 500GB but it also have a Small SDD Memory of 64 or 32 MB! Looking on the Windows HD Administration I have 2 Hard Disks. I believe the 2 is due to the SSD. Does Ubuntu/Kubuntu 18 and also 20 recognize that?! Kiitos Palyon guys!!

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely the result of a BIOS setting. Try this:

1. Reboot your machine and enter the BIOS Setup
2. Navigate to "Settings" ⇢ "System Configuration" ⇢ "SATA Operation"
3. If the value is "RAID On", then change it to "AHCI"
4. Save and reboot

Some Dell notebooks are pre-configured to support Intel's "Rapid Restore Technology" by default, which can confuse the installer into thinking there is a RAID device when one does not exist. Using AHCI mode ensures each device is seen independently.

Hope this helps.